# Does it matter if this is used in a C++ setter?

Tags: c++, this, setter

Suppose I have a c++ class with a private variable, x. For it's setter, is there any difference using `this`? Is there the potential for unwanted / unexpected behavior is I don't use `this`?

Setter:

```
void setX(double input)
{
   x = input;
}
```

Setter using `this`:

```
void setX(double x)
{
   this->x = x;
}
```

Comment: ... do you mean `x = input;` in the first part?

Comment: @bdonlan, sorry typo and fixed

Comment: Compile it and compare the disassembly.  I suspect they will be exactly the same, but I haven't checked.

Comment: The only place IMHO where `this->` makes sense is in an inheritance hierarchy where you want to call a base class method, without injecting or some crazy syntax...

Comment: @Nim: I think it'd be beneficial if you could expand a full answer from your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of two-phase lookup for class templates, `this` might be required to

1. explicitly state you mean a member
2. because of lookup rules, the compiler might assume another entity that is visible there is meant

*(see the first example)* Both are equivalent.

In a non-template situation, you usually avoid using `this`; the generated code will be the same, thus there won't be any difference *(see the second example)*.
The reason for this is that the compiler will try to lookup every symbol it sees. The first place to lookup is in class-scope (except for block and function scope). If it finds a symbol of that name there, it will emit `this` implicitly. In reality, member functions are just ordinary functions with an invisible parameter.

```
class Foo {
    void foo () { x = 0; }
    void bar () const { std::cout << x; }
    void frob();
    int x;
};
void Foo::frob() {}
```

Is actually transformed into

```
class Foo {        
    int x;
};
inline void foo (Foo *const this) { this->x = 0; }
inline void bar (Foo const * const this) { std::cout << this->x; }
void frob (Foo * const this) {}
```

by the compiler.

---

Behavioral example for `this` in templates:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "::foo()\n";
}

template <typename>
struct Base {
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Base<T>::foo()\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived_using_this : Base<Derived_using_this<T> > {
    void bar() const { this->foo(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived_not_using_this : Base<Derived_not_using_this<T> > {
    void bar() const { foo(); }
};


int main () {
    Derived_not_using_this<void>().bar();
    Derived_using_this<void>().bar();
}
```

Output:

```
::foo()
Base<T>::foo()
```

Example assembly for non-template:

With `this`:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, %esi
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
leave
ret
```

Without `this`:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, %esi
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
leave
ret
```

Verify yourself:

test.cc:

```
#include <stdio.h> // Don't use this. I just did so for nicer assembly.

class Foo {
public:
    Foo () : i(0) {}

    void with_this() const { printf ("%d", this->i); }
    void without_this() const { printf ("%d", i); }
private:
    int i;
};


int main () {
    Foo f;
    f.with_this();
    f.without_this();
}
```

Run `g++ -S test.cc`. You'll see a file named `test.s`, there you can search for the function names.

Comment: Can you please expand upon the non-template situation?

Comment: Code is nice, but explanation?

Answer (score 5):

These two code fragments (assuming they're inline member functions, since there's no `ClassName::` bit) are exactly equivalent. Use whichever you prefer. I would tend to recommend against naming parameters the same as member variables though; it's too easy get them mixed up.

Comment: Naming conventions solve all this. _classMember, methodParameter, localVariable, and GlobalVariable :)

Comment: What if there was a class name, how would that change this?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I've always preferred `ClassMember`, `_methodArg`, `localVariable`, and no globals myself. :-)

Comment: @Elpezmuerto All he meant was that it isn't clear from your code snippet whether the setter is a member function or a standalone function. But the question wouldn't make sense if it were the latter, because there would be no `this` pointer.

Comment: @Mahmoud:  Leading underscores are reserved by the standard.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I thought it was leading double underscores?

Comment: @James: FWIW I prefer `classMember`, `methodArg`, `localVariable`, and don't give them the same names. If my function is so big that I've forgotten what the parameters are called, then accidentally shadowing them with a local isn't my problem -- worse, I've forgotten what the function does! In theory there's a risk of naming a new member the same as some parameter, and then trying to use the new member in that function and accidentally using the parameter instead. In practice, this doesn't seem to happen, so personally I don't think it's worth mutilating my code with prefixes.

Comment: @John: not when followed by a lowercase letter in function scope. `_MethodArg` can't be used as a parameter name, but `_methodArg` can.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right, just looked it up.  You're not allowed to use double underscore or underscore followed by an upper-case letter.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't really do it for risk of collision, really (that is a very very minor concern).  I do it so when I read the code I can immediately see what is a member, what is a local variable, and what is a function argument.  Helps me parse the code quicker when I come back to it after a few months...

Comment: @James: and in global scope, underscore followed by lowercase is reserved too. I forget whether that's "global scope" as in file scope, or any namespace scope. So John's implied advice not to use initial underscores at all isn't necessarily a bad idea. It's easier than remembering the rules.

Comment: @James: I followed the Symbian naming guidelines for a couple of years, initial `a` for arguments, initial `i` for data members ("instance variables"). Couldn't be bothered with it, really, and in particular I really couldn't see the point of distinguishing between parameters and (other) local variables. But I prefer it to underscores when I'm using CamelCase names.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Looks like it's reserved in 'global namespace'.  As I only use them for method parameters, it should be safe, though I might eventually need to do something like `::_reserved_name` if I accidentally masked it I suppose.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I can see how it would be a bother to some, but I make heavy use of Visual Assist X and it's auto-complete features... being able to quickly distinguish between local variables and argument by typing `_` and narrowing it down is useful to me.  I tend to use `Get` methods for the same reason, even if they aren't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The this variant makes a syntactical difference when templates are involved. However, it is semantically the same; the `this->` variant just makes it clearer you are accessing the current objects and avoids potential collisions.

Answer (score 2):

```
void setX(double x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
```

If the member variable `x` would be obscured by the argument `x`, then `this->` is explicitly needed to ensure you are assigning to the correct variable.  Otherwise it is not needed.

But I don't recommend you name your argument the same thing as a member variable anyway.  The first example you give has fewer pitfalls.

Comment: You might want to look at the question again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code will work, it is poor code and likely to confuse somebody.

Much better to give the "setX()" parameter a different name.

e.g.

```
void setX(double new_x)
{
   x = new_x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter. I've worked with code conventions stating that all private vars should be accessed through *this* in order to make the code more readable. But other than readability I don't think there is any difference.